# Visualforce pie chart to start at "12 o'clock"

Tags: visualforce, charts

All Visualforce pie charts I see online and the one's I'm developing now seem to just randomly place wedges on the chart. **Update**: the first wedge is placed with a horizontal center line pointing to 90º

[image]

What I'm after is some option to force starting at the same spot. I think "12 o'clock" is the most common one but anything will do. Compare with this example Google chart:

[image]

Any ideas? Couldn't find anything in the reference of `<apex:chart>` or `<apex:pieSeries>` and the generated Javascript looks scary (plus probably my change would break the moment someone starts interacting with it).

Comment: I think you should submit an Idea; I'd vote for it.

Comment: The wedge placement is not random. The middle of the first wedge is always horizontal and on the right. I see that Visualforce pie charts fills the pie anticlockwise, whereas Google does more sensible clockwise fill. I think most people would want to go through the pie chart clockwise while reading the legend.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've gravitated towards using the [Google Charts Image Api](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/).  Being imaged based it can still work in scenarios where javascript isn't available (i.e. rendering as PDFs or Conga Merges).  It also has a ton of parameters to control just about everything (including where the initial value is).

Unfortunately it's been recently deprecated, which for Google, means after 3 years they have the option to start phasing it out.

Comment: This has always been my goto-solution as well until they deprecated it — such a shame!