# Google chart API vs analytical report chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, analytics

I have created bar charts in salesforce using google chart api and they work fine. I have also created charts using reports and dash boards in salesforce. Displaying the charts in visualforce by using 'analytics:reportChart' is taking too long to load the chart. So I am using apex:iframe and dash board image url to display it in the visualforce page. So my question is, between google api charts and analytics:reportChart which is better ? and why analytics:reportChart takes so long to disaply ?. Is there a way to make it load fast ?

Comment: FYI, there is also the option of using an apex:chart. That avoids the cost of calling out to Google but is otherwise similar, so I'd argue it is better. (It requires you to have calculated the values just like Google charts does.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to discourage you but I gave up on VF charts after I couldn't get [Visualforce pie chart to start at "12 o'clock"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/visualforce-pie-chart-to-start-at-12-oclock) to work.

I guess you could experiment with caching of whole VF page? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm, `cache` and `expires` attributes.

Other than that - generic tips & hints for improving [performance of Visualforce](http://www.scribd.com/doc/216085828/Salesforce-Visualforce-Best-Practices)? Check the viewstate, fire up developer console, check browser's console for JS error messages, stop using Internet Explorer... ;)